# How to add an image into GUI with an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-3.6

Using tkinter, I want to add the if statement in the GUI code where if a certain name gets chosen (by random) i want to display an image of the person chosen. For example, if Valkyrie gets chosen when picking defenders, i want her name and this photo

[image]

to show up. Heres my code for my GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
import tkinter as tk
import random

names = ['Sledge','Thatcher','Ash','Thermite','Twitch','Montagne','Glaz','Fuze','Blitz','IQ','Buck','Blackbeard','Capitão','Hibana']
name = ["Smoke","Mute","Castle","Pulse","Doc","Rook","Kapkan","Tachanka","Jäger","Bandit","Frost","Valkyrie","Caveira","Echo"]
root = tkinter.Tk()
def pickName():
    nameLabel.configure(text=random.choice(names))
def pickName1():
    nameLabel.configure(text=random.choice(name))



root.title("Operator Picker")

root.geometry("1920x300")

nameLabel = tkinter.Label(root, text="", font=('Helvetica', 32))
nameLabel.pack()
Grid()

pickButton1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Pick Attack", command=pickName, 
height=100, width=100)
pickButton1.pack(side=tkinter.LEFT)
pickButton2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="Pick Defend", command=pickName1, 
height=100, width=100)
pickButton2.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

I tried to use an if statement, but there's no variable i can attach it to. All help appreciated, thanks!